# Change document in open window in macOS app

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, document

I am writing a document-based application for macOS. I am trying to write a feature that changes the active document in the current window (in order to be able to cycle through the next/previous documents in a folder, the way one can do with image-browser apps).

What command should I be calling to open a different document in the current window? The documentation suggests that openDocument might do this, but when I run

`documentController.openDocument(nextFile!)`

then I just get an NSOpenPanel which opens a new document in a separate window. How can I open a different document in the current window - with a URL I specify in coding, rather than through an OpenPanel?

Answer (score 1):

You can't open a document in the window of another document. Instead of

`NSDocumentController` -> `document` -> `window`

do it the other way around

`app delegate` -> `window/view` -> `document`.

The window is owned by the app delegate or a controller and the view controller of the window owns the document. The document is created with

```
convenience init(contentsOf url: URL, ofType typeName: String) throws
```

**Edit:**

The documentation of `addWindowController(_:)` of `NSDocument` suggests that it's possible to replace the document of a window controller:

> You cannot attach a window controller to more than one document at a time. The default implementation of this method removes the passed-in window controller from the document to which it is attached, if it is already attached to one, then sends it a document message with self as the argument. It also ignores redundant invocations.

and yes, it does work in my test app:

```
let prevDocument = windowController.document
let newDocument = Document(contentsOf: newURL, ofType: myDocumentType) // add do-catch
NSDocumentController.shared.addDocument(newDocument);
newDocument.addWindowController(windowController)
prevDocument.close()
```

Comment: So, I've been trying to think about what this approach would involve, and my big worry is: does it go around the Cocoa document architecture? I tried doing this app working against the document architecture before and it was a huge buggy mess. I'd like to keep this as close to the prescribed methods for documents as possible.

Comment: @DisplacedHoser Which features of `NSDocument` do you want to use?

Comment: Open and save, and their connection to the file system, for sure. The connection to views/windows also seems really helpful to me - I based my code off of a tutorial (https://www.raywenderlich.com/613-windows-and-windowcontroller-tutorial-for-macos) that straightforwardly links a document with a window. I'd just like to be able to change which document is in a window, and I'm not really sure how to do that. My earlier version tried to have multiple documents in one window - rebuilding the document/window connection from scratch - and that turned out way too complicated and breakable.

Comment: Thanks - the new version looks close to what I'm looking for. Two problems seem to remain when I try it, which I'm guessing are connected. First, the close() command gives me an odd error: "Ambiguous reference to member 'close()'". Second, the filename of the current window's document changes, but not the window's content - possibly because it hasn't been able to close the old one?